# How do I use this code and make it so it gets rid of teams who haven't played yet or the (tsc) in the API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

API LINK: http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp

**MY CODE**

```
/////
//credit to @Aditya from StackOverflow for helping me edit this code
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#search').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
                dataType: 'jsonp', //data in jsonp
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'loadScoreboard', 
                success: function (data) {
                    var text = data['games'];
                    console.log(text); 
                    var str = '';  
                    var textsearch = $('#text').val(); 

                    if(textsearch!=null)
                    {
                        str = '';
                        for (var key in text)
                        { 
                            if(text[key].hasOwnProperty('htn') && text[key].hasOwnProperty('hts'))
                            {
                                if(text[key]['htn'].toLowerCase().indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                                {
                                    console.log(text[key]);
                                    str= text[key]['htn']+ " vs "+ text[key]['atn']+ " score : "+ text[key]['hts']+"-"+text[key]['ats']+"\n";
                                }
                                if( text[key]['atn'].toLowerCase().indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase())!=-1)
                                    str += text[key]['atn'] + " vs "+ text[key]['htn'] + " score : "+ text[key]['ats']+"-"+text[key]['hts']+"\n";
                            }
                         }
                         console.log("str: " + str);
                        $('#result').html('<p>' + str + '</p>');
                    }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Right now it displays teams who's games are not played yet but how do I make it so it gets rid of teams with no tsc (take a look at the object)?

Comment: your "for" walkes all the teams. then your first "if" makes only team with 'htn' & 'hts' show. add a condition to your first "if".

Comment: `if(text[key].hasOwnProperty('htn') && text[key].hasOwnProperty('hts') && teamHasPlayed )`

Comment: how do you know if a team has played?

Comment: So where do I paste this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out those games that have an empty tsc value. For example (I don't know why you call that variable `text` but I've edited my answer to reflect the question):

```
var text = data.games;
text = text.filter(function (game) {
  return game.tsc !== '';
});
```

You would add this before the loop.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5f9b4/2/)

Comment: Right under the `str=''`, yes.

Comment: It still displays games which haven't been played yet

Comment: Sorry, made an edit to the `return` line. My error, sorry. It should be `return game.tsc !== '';`

Comment: There we go Thank you so much

Comment: i swear, one day people will even ask that you paste the code for them and send you the source files via email